# TLA+ translated result parse failed

Tags: tla+

my TLA+ spec write by PlusCalc compile to TLA+ succeed, but parse failed:

THE SPEC: https://justpaste.it/39pru

where is the error location in PlusCalc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer on the semi-official Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tlaplus/x3G2DC91fpc/r-_VpqjZBQAJ

(Mirror: http://discuss.tlapl.us/msg03251.html)